# How to combine Figure Label (cross-reference) and Figure width in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I would like to include a pdf Figure in my Quarto Document and render everything to docx. This is my general setup:

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "A"
format: 
  docx:
    reference-doc: "config/template_word.docx"
---

Please see @fig-over for an interesting overview. 

![Overview.](Figs/Fig.pdf){#fig-over}
```

Now the this works like charm. However, I also want to change the width of the Figure. And I don't know how to combine the labeling and customizing the figure width. For exmaple, this does not work:

```
![Overview.](Figs/Fig.pdf){ #fig-over, width=250px}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
![Overview.](Figs/Fig.pdf){#fig-over width='250px'}
```

or

```
![Overview.](Figs/Fig.pdf){#fig-over width=250px}
```

*Note*: Be careful with whitespaces, e.g. `{#fig-over width= '250px'}` does not work.